# Warning of pending edits on mobile app

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits, mobile-app

I just tried to suggest an edit for a post via the Android mobile app and once I finally hit the "Suggest" button I got an error saying I couldn't edit that post.

After checking on my desktop I discovered that another edit had been suggested, so I was unable to edit it until that was addressed. While i imagine I was probably just very unlucky and an edit went in just before mine, it would have been nice to have been alerted to that fact, either when it happened or just via the final error message.

Could an improvement be made to the mobile app to provide a clearer cause of the error in this case and cases like it?