# iOS app does not warn that a subsequent edit has been made

Tags: feature-request, edits, suggested-edits, ios-app

#### TL;DR

You have a draft of an edit to a post on the iPhone app. Then, you submit that draft. If there has been a subsequent edit, whilst you were still editing, then there is no warning that you are about to attempt to overwrite an approved edit, with your own edit of a *previous* version.

Your edit will be rejected, and so, your rejection count is incremented.

---

I had a draft of an edit of the question, [How to use 'either or'?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/111527/how-to-use-either-or), sitting on my iPhone overnight. The following day, when I reopened the Stack Exchange app, I saw the edit, and after a quick visual check, I hit the submit link.

Later, I saw that the edit had been [rejected](https://ell.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/49714):

> [image: My attempted edit]

I then checked Nathan's edit, to see what the change should have been, and to my surprise I saw that the change was the same (well, actually, less - as the ellipsis had been omitted from the title).

> [image: Actual edit history]

So, I could not figure out why my edit has been rejected.

After a while I realised that my edit has attempted to remove the tags added by Jaspar. Again, I could not figure out with that had happened, as I rarely edit tags, and cetainly had not done so in this case.

I, then, realised (after noticing, at the lower part of my edit, the two *removed* tags) that I must have opened the edit up on my iPhone *prior to* Jaspar making the tag changes, and then submitted my proposed edit *after* Jasper's tag changes had taken effect.

So, *[assuming that my edit was rejected due to my attempted inadvertant tag changes](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3355/was-my-edit-rejected-for-the-inadvertant-tag-changes-or-some-other-reason)*... this situation could have been avoided had the app notified me, when I hit the submit link, that a subsequent edit had been made. The "normal" browser based web page notifies the user with a banner at the top, is a edit has been submitted whilst you are making an edit, so shouldn't the iOS app do the same?

---

- iOS app version: 1.3.2
- iOS version: 7.1.2

---

Note that my issue is different from [Warning of pending edits on mobile app](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270101/warning-of-pending-edits-on-mobile-app?rq=1), as my question deals with accepted edits, rather than pending edits.

Comment: You should probably update iOS and app first

Comment: @Cai - ah yes, I see that the latest app version is 1.6.1. Hmm, unfortunately, 1.3.2 is the latest version that iOS 7.1.2 will support. Has this issue been fixed in subsequent versions of the app, then?

Comment: I don't think so (I haven't read your post in enough detail to know for sure—I'll have another look once I'm home), but generally anything other than a support question doesn't really make sense for old unsupported OS/app versions :)

Comment: @Cai - Ok, thank you. Unfortunately, I am somewhat reluctant to upgrade my iPhone 5 to the latest iOS version, as I fear that it will get even slower than it already is... :-)